# Youtube brand channel embedding using iframe

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have a YouTube channel (brand) linked on my personal account. My problem is I cannot get any way to embed my "brand channel" on our organization website. I want to embed player on my site that will display my channel activities specially my live streams.

My channel ID is UCQK3B7dSiwH3F1zg3JOThLw.

I tried:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UCQK3B7dSiwH3F1zg3JOThLw" width="480" height="400"></iframe>
```

But I get this error:

```
{
  "cpn": "W8El0IDdHj8fczkE",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": "true",
  "vsk": "false",
  "ven": "false",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "0",
  "vec": "null",
  "vvol": "0.21",
  "state": "80",
  "debug_error": {
    "errorCode": "api.invalidparam",
    "errorDetail": "invalidVideodata.1",
    "message": "An error occurred. Please try again later.",
    "messageKey": "YTP_ERROR_GENERIC_WITHOUT_LINK",
    "subreason": ""
  },
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "user_qual": "hd720",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(Intel(R)_HD_Graphics_4600_Direct3D11_vs_5_0_ps_5_0)",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Fri Mar 16 2018 12:07:54 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"
}
```

What did I miss or misunderstand technically or legally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is possible to embed the entire chanel but for embed a playlist you can do it like this ...

Example playlist, take de "V" requesParam value "uXTsx1FMCcI"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXTsx1FMCcI&list=UUQK3B7dSiwH3F1zg3JOThLw

Embeded code, pass it in the src value

```
`<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uXTsx1FMCcI?enablejsapi=1" id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"  frameborder="0"></iframe>`
```

You will get message saying that owner has disabled playing in other websites but this you can configure it in your youtube settings